# what does "for other nation nations to aspire to" in this text mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

The text :

"education is unequalled the world over, and serves as a ***benchmark for other nation nations to aspire to***"

what does ""for other ***nation nations to aspire to***"

why is ***"nation"*** mention two times? will that have another meaning?

I will be grateful if someone explains them simply in different words.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an obvious typographical error.

Comment: look at my comment down in the answer

Comment: You need to add a credit/link to the source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the first 'nation' is a mistake to be honest since it makes no sense in the sentence.

So it should be 'serves as a benchmark for other nations to aspire to'.

It means it is a model of excellent education and other nations should try and have the same type of high education in their own countries as well.

Comment: since I took this part of text from reliable resource, it was difficult for me to say that there is a mistake. I thought this like kind of manipulation of language. Thanks